# ssh proxy using -W host:port

Tags: centos, ssh, proxy

I'm trying to use intermediate machine to connect to a remote host but I'm doing something wrong and not sure what.

I have added to my intermediate box /etc/ssh/sshd_config following lines:

```
Match User deploy
PermitOpen  any
AllowTcpForwarding yes
ForceCommand echo 'This account can only be used for deployments'
```

I can ssh from that intermediate box onto the target system no problem but I was hoping to be able to just execute a command like one below to connect via my proxy box:

```
ssh deploy@dev-linux-03 -W TARGET_IP:22
```

But I'm getting different response:

```
 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.3

 Protocol mismatch.
```

Anything obvious I've missed?

Comment: What does the log on the intermediate server say?

Comment: Not much: "localhost sshd[14979]: Accepted publickey for deploy from xxx", ssh in verbose mode shows: channel_connect_stdio_fwd TARGET_IP:22

Comment: Response looks similar if I just telnet on port 22, I thought -W will create ssh connection but maybe I need to create tunnel first, or do it differently?

Comment: If what you want is an SSH session from the intermediate server to the final server, then this is not the way to do it. `-W` opens a socket to the server/port you've specified, it doesn't pass the actual SSH connection on. I'm linking another question that has an answer with the kind of SSH config I think you need for this.

Comment: Can you ssh -vvv so we have more feedback?

Comment: have you tried taking out the echo statement?

Answer (score 2):

You specified the command incorrectly. The correct way to type the command would be like this:

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand='ssh -W %h:%p user@intermediate-host' user@target-host
```

If you need this frequently, you can add it to `~/.ssh/config` like this:

```
Host target-host
    User user
    ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p user@intermediate-host
```

Then you only need to type `ssh target-host` to connect.